# Переменная не определена

Tags: python

у меня есть класс в котором есть функция `process`

```
class MHandler():
   cid = [18279831, 4436809]
   def process(self, event):
      for i in cid:
         print(i)
```

когда функция вызывается, я пытаюсь перебрать массив `cid` но вижу ошибку

```
NameError: name 'cid' is not defined
```

что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: прочитайте ошибку, там же написано что вы сделать забыли.

Answer (score 1):

К переменной класса надо обращаться или с именем класса `MHandler.cid` или с `self.cid`

```py
class MHandler():
    cid = [18279831, 4436809]
    def process(self, event):
        for i in self.cid:
            print(i)

>>> x = MHandler()
>>> x.process(123)
18279831
4436809
```

---

PS Как правильно заметил [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325735/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0#comment2342758_1325739), в данном случае нет разницы, как обратится. Но в общем случае:

- с именем класса идет обращение к переменной класса, которая одинаковая для всех экземпляров класса
- а с self идет обращение к переменной экземпляра класса - она у каждого экземпляра своя

Разница будет заметна после присвоения нового значения одной из этих переменных, тогда они будут отличаться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё объяснить в чём будет разница если сделать в одном варианте и в другом.

Comment: @CrazyElf В данном случае, никакой разницы, cid это переменная класса, и так и так можно к ней обратиться - ничего не изменится. Или что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @user459826 В данном случае да. Но в общем случае переменная класса одинаковая для всех экземпляров класса, а вот переменная экземпляра класса - она у каждого экземпляра своя, и это будет заметно, если начать этот список как-то менять.

Comment: @CrazyElf Полностью согласен, добавил ваше замечание в ответ. Спаасибо!